# If you buy a gamepass from a group game, will it go to the owner of the group, or straight into the group funds?

Tags: roblox

If you buy a gamepass from a group game, will it go to the owner of the group, or straight into the group funds. I am the owner of the group and group game, so if I wanted to buy a gamepass for 100 robux, would 70 go back to me or into the group? I don't want to waste 30 robux!

I did my best to research this, but I couldn't find anything. One thing I do know is that group t shirts go to group funds.

If you think you can help, it would be greatly appreciated!
[image: The top search results (first one is my question and results underneath aren't any better. Also, ROBLOX has terrible support.]

The top search results (first one is my question and results underneath aren't any better. Also, ROBLOX has terrible support. I tried to research, but there was no help. Scrolled 5 and a half pages. If you know the answer, please tell me! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried *actually* buying it? Like doing what you've stated?

Comment: Telling people to stop downvoting is only going to make people downvote more.  If you don't want downvotes, make your question better.  Don't tell us you researched, *show* us you did.  Show us what you found, why it didn't answer your question.

Comment: An answer of yes or no doesn't fit our minimum character limit, @Anthony.  We expect answerers to expand upon that.  None of that matters for your question, however.  You don't want downvotes; that's understandable.  But the way to ensuring you don't is by *showing* the research you've put in.  Insisting the question is good as is just isn't going to cut it.  That's the best way to ensure you get a good answer, in hopefully a decent amount of time.

Comment: That's not showing research.  That's showing your search.

Comment: @Frank I added more... I couldn't get in any research... so I put that.

Comment: Well, then you're probably going to get downvotes.  It's one of the primary reasons to do so.

Comment: okay no worries

Answer (score 1):

It will go straight to group funds but if the owner decides to take all the robux for it self or get some of it it will transfer to its account but I think there is a fee of 20% so if you buy it I THINK they wont get the exact amount you bought it for

Comment: Hi Olive, thanks for the answer! Can you please add some more punctuation, as it's currently difficult to read.

Answer (score -1):

It will go into the group funds, but if the owner just creates it and doesn't put it in a group it will go to the creator not the group but I an owner does it will go to the group